# How to manually GC on a Gitblit server?

Tags: gitblit

How to remove a commit on my Gitblit repo without using experimental GC (= garbage collection)? After force push, this delicate commit has no reference anymore but is still visible over GUI. Can I install Git on server (next to Gitblit) and run

```
git gc --prune=now
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
```

?

This delicate commit ID is not existent at file system, I guess because of packing.

---

Gitblit v1.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Powertools plugin](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit-powertools-plugin) then issue the GC command via SSH.  See this [asciicast](https://asciinema.org/a/9342) for more info.

Comment: Works. I had to put `git.sshPort = 29418` in `gitblit.properties` and restart Gitblit. Then `ssh admin@127.0.0.1 -p 29418 git gc ~user/repo.git`. Thanks.